# Using enum as template type argument in C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums, visual-c++-2008

are there any restrictions / problems using an enum as template (type) argument in C++?

Example:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    A, B, C, D, E
};

template <typename _t>
class MyTemplate
{
public:
   _t value;

   void func(const _t& param) { /* .... */ }
};

// ....

MyTemplate<MyEnum> MyInstance;
```

---

My actual problem using MSVC++ via VS 2008 (SP1) on Win32/x86 are several compilation errors (= errors reported by the compiler) in association with classes using enums as template arguments. As my project unfortunately has become a bit complex (you can consider that as a design error :P), the template classes raising these errors are derived, nested and even specialised on a class with enum template parameter.

Trying to build, the compiler reports many wrong/useless errors such as "C2059: syntax error: 'public'" in lines where there is only a comment. Many of them I could fix by replacing in methods similar to the one in the example the const _t& param by _t (i.e. copying the parameter), but neither could I fix all of these errors nor do I have a clue why this "helps". **I know, the simple example above compiles w/o errors.

Using int instead of enum, my project compiles w/o errors.

Thanks in advance for any hint or tip!

---

**Edit**:

After all, I seriously consider this as a compiler bug. When I tried to reproduce the errors with simplified code, I got them only in 50 % of all "builds", not very deterministic:
E.g. tried to compile, and it reported these errors. Rebuild - no change. Deleted a comment, build - no change. Rebuild - and then: no errors, compiles fine.

I've already met a few compiler bugs (2 or 3 I guess within 20k lines of code), but this one seems to me very strange.
Any suggestions how to figure out if it **is** the compiler?

Comment: "Trying to build, the compiler reports many wrong/useless errors" Those "useless" errors often have a very detailed description of what/and where went wrong. Just read compiler output instead of "error list".

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I did. I always do so ^^

But it didn't help me... Errors: error C2059: syntax error : 'public' error C2143: syntax error : missing '>' before ';' error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}' fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found (and then some of other errors, not related to this question) all of these only appear when using the enum and vanish when using int

Comment: This looks perfectly fine to me.  This is either a compiler error or your error, and if you're going to guess, the 99.9% bet is that it's you.  But there is nothing wrong with the snippets you've posted.  Please post a small sample that's complete within itself and the exact compiler errors it creates.

Comment: I agree - see the edit. just wondering why the int type compiles fine

Comment: The code snippet compiles fine on my MSVC compiler, no warnings or errors !!

Comment: Premature optimization is what I've heard.

Comment: sry, I'm not quite sure I know what you mean.... is it the const & ?
the const is for const correctness, which is quite important in that project. the reference -- habit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to the original question:

> are there any restrictions / problems using an enum as template (type) argument in C++?

I didn't find any - and I don't think there are any. It might turn out to be a bad idea because this technique it is not used that often, so there might be a few (more) compiler bugs relating to this, just as Potatoswatter said.
Consider the following example:

```
enum MyEnum : int
{
    A, B, C, D
};

template <typename _t> class MyTemplate
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "not using any specialisation" << endl;
    }
};
    template <> class MyTemplate <MyEnum>
    {
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout << "MyEnum specialisation" << endl;
        }
    };
    template<> class MyTemplate <int>
    {
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout << "int specialisation" << endl;
        }
    };

template <typename _t> void print(_t param)
{
    MyTemplate<_t> m;
    m.print();
}


int main()
{
    print(A);
    print(5);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> MyEnum specialisation
>   int specialisation

For these simple examples, **everything works fine and as expected** and the enum works perfectly as any other type as template type argument (= I don't see any reason for problems).

Originally, I introduced the example in the question to show what I meant with that question (enum as template type argument, show possible usages as member or method argument type and so on). To provide a bit of background, i.e. **why** I asked that question (imagine I asked "are there any problems with int"), I mentioned these strange problems compiling my actual project.
I'm sorry I could not extract a snippet of it that is complete in itself and reproducing the errors, the least I could get were 2k lines of code splitted into 4 files, where a "syntax error : 'public'" and some other syntax error were raised when I compiled the project, and they appeared / disappeared under certain circumstances, when deleting a comment or re-building (= deleting the intermediate files). Unfortunately, rebuilding does not help with the original project, where I had to replace a specialisation from an enum type to int.

So, thanks everyone for your hints and tips. The underlying problem seems to me to be a compiler bug, what makes the question a bit pointless, as the answer seems to be just *"no - there are no restrictions using an enum as template type argument"*. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are restrictions. For example, you cannot use an anonymous enum as a template argument according to C++03 `14.3.1[temp.arg.type]/2`

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

So the following code is not valid in C++03:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) {}

enum {A};

int main() {
  f(A);
}
```

It is valid in C++11 though.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC handles enum (value) template parameters strangely. Enums are promoted to `int` improperly sometimes and the operators aren't defined properly. It seems that they don't really test the template engine with `enum` types.

Proving it's a compiler bug is simple: put valid code in and observe whether it successfully compiles. <s>Your example is obviously compliant, so the problem (or the mistake, anyway) is theirs.</s>

**Edit**: on closer inspection you say that the example does *not* reproduce the bug. Neither we nor anyone else can help you until you produce an example that does.

Comment: One can prove that a compiler has a bug only by two ways:

a) validate against the relevant Standards
b) Reading the documentation and checking if it is a known issue/defect

Comment: The OP isn't supplying an enum *value* as the template parameter though - the enum *type* is the parameter.