# How can I use an enumeration as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, enums, non-type-template-parameter

I would like to use a template class to provide some common functionality to some child classes that are very similar.  The only variation is the enumeration that each uses.

This is the parent class

```
template<typename T> class E_EnumerationBase : public SimpleElement
{
public:
    E_EnumerationBase();
    virtual bool setValue(QString choice);
    virtual T getState();

protected:
    T state;
    QHash<QString, T> dictionary;
};

template<typename T> E_EnumerationBase<T>::E_EnumerationBase() {
    state = 0;
}

template<typename T> bool E_EnumerationBase<T>::setValue(QString choice) {
    T temp;
    temp = dictionary.value(choice, 0);
    if (temp == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    value = choice;
    state = temp;
    return true;
}

template<typename T> T E_EnumerationBase<T>::getState() {
    return state;
}
```

This is one of the children

```
enum TableEventEnum {
    NO_VALUE = 0,
    ATTRACT = 1,
    OPEN = 2,
    CLOSED = 3
};

class E_TableEvent : public E_EnumerationBase<enum TableEventEnum>
{
public:
    E_TableEvent();
};
```

This is the constructor

```
E_TableEvent::E_TableEvent()
{
    state = NO_VALUE;
    dictionary.insert("attract", ATTRACT);
    dictionary.insert("open", OPEN);
    dictionary.insert("closed", CLOSED);
}
```

The linker is throwing this error:

```
e_tableevent.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to `E_EnumerationBase<TableEventEnum>::E_EnumerationBase()'
```

Can an enumeration be used as the parameter to a template like this?

Comment: Is your constructor definition in the header file?

Comment: No, the definition is in a separate source file.  The error shows up on link.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Enumerations can be template parameters in exactly the same way that ints can.

```
enum Enum { ALPHA, BETA };

template <Enum E> class Foo {
    // ...
};

template <> void Foo <ALPHA> :: foo () {
    // specialise
}

class Bar : public Foo <BETA> {
    // OK
}
```

But you simply haven't provided a definition for `E_EnumerationBase::E_EnumerationBase()`

This isn't a problem with templates or inheritence. It's the same as if you written this:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo ();
}
int main () {
    Foo foo;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post it to [ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com) or similar in such a form that that is the only error? It would be helpful to see line numbers etc. For now I don't believe that `public E_EnumerationBase<enum TableEventEnum>` compiles at all.

Comment: Are enumerations in templates treated as value arguments?  I would like to use it as a type.

Comment: If you want to instantinate `Foo<typename T>` with `Foo<MyType>` that's ok whether `MyType` is a class or enum or any other type. You can also instantinate `Foo<int N>` with `Foo<integer_contsant_expression>` and that's also ok. Provided, of course, that the substitution makes sense. The implementations should not write `if(i<T)` or `N value;`

Comment: How do you enforce `template <int E>` only takes values `ALPHA` and `BETA`? What stops someone from instantiating with `E=99`? Does it at least generate a warning?

Comment: With `template<int E>` you can instantiate with any `int`, with `template<Enum E>` you can instantiate with any `Enum`. Normal int/enum casting constraints apply.

Comment: This doesn't show enumerations being used as template parameters. This just shows enums being cast to ints.

Comment: [No](http://pastebin.com/EYF2eDAc), these are enum-typed parameters. Enum *values* may be type-converted to ints, but enum *types* don't.

Comment: @spraff: your link there is what I was expecting your answer to contain

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Edited.

Comment: *Enumerations can be template parameters in exactly the same way that ints can..."* - Is that C++03 or C++11? Do you know how well earlier compilers supported it? "Earlier" means compilers like GCC 4.4, Clang 3.2, MSC 14.0. (We are in a special hell due to backwards compatibility).

Comment: It looks like here is a similar question: [Using enum as template type argument in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485472/608639)

Comment: I must say that the fact that you named your enum as 'Enum' made me spend quite some time trying to understand this. I suggest changing it to something like 'Greek' to make the example clearer

Comment: Is it now (C++11) also possible with `enum class` ?

Answer (score 9):

The syntax goes for value arguments like it is for typename arguments. Basically, you just replace `typename` with the name of your `enum`:

```
enum Foo { Bar, Frob };

template <Foo F> struct Boom {};  // primary template
template <> struct Boom<Bar> {};  // specialization of whole class

...

template <> void Boom<Frob>::somefun() {}  // specialization of single member
```

Comment: Are you suggesting the enum is being used for its value and not as a type?  Primarily, I'm trying to restrict the values in the hash table.

Comment: "Don't write serious template code unless you seriously understand templates"  - that's a bit arrogant. Encouraging feedback would be more helpful.

Comment: @dlchambers: It wasn't intended that way and you are right. I removed that section altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move definition of template function to separate source file.

There it wouldn't be compiled at all, because *templates can't be compiled*, only template instances can.

Your code in separate file isn't get compiled, that's why you actually have no definition for `E_EnumerationBase<TableEventEnum>::E_EnumerationBase()`. That's why you get linker error.

Just move all template code to your header.

Comment: *There [the enum] wouldn't be compiled at all"* - Enums don't get compiled *per se*. They take up no space in the class. This is in contrast to, say, a static int which requires a definition and causes an allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, as you seem to use Qt: Just have a look at `Q_ENUM`, `QMetaEnum` and `QMetaEnum::fromType`. These may come handy to initialize your dictionary.