# Why can't I use a const enum data member as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type-template-parameter

```
class myclass {
  private:
    const myenum value;
  public:
    enum myenum { first, second }
    myclass(myenum value) : value(value) {}

    template < /* enable if myclass::value == myclass::myenum::first */ >
    void myfunc();
    template < /* enable if myclass::value == myclass::myenum::second */ >
    void myfunc();
}

int main(){
  myclass instance(myclass::myenum::first);
  instance.myfunc();
}
```

`value` is *mode* at witch `myfunc()` operates if you will. So far all my attempts have failed. Please tell whether it is possible to achieve the desired behavior and give me your suggestions

Comment: Is [Using an enumeration as a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116267/using-an-enumeration-as-a-template-parameter) helpful?

Comment: In my case enum template parameter is not given explicitly. `const myenum value` has to be used as a template parameter if it is even possible

Answer (score 2):

`const myenum value;` is a run-time value, which cannot be used to control the instantiation of `myfunc` at compile-time. If you want to do that, you need to pass `myenum` as a template parameter to `myclass`:

```
template <myenum value>
class myclass {
    // ...
};
```

Otherwise, you can use an `if` statement inside `myfunc` at run-time:

```
void myfunc()
{
    if(value == myenum::first) { /* ... */ }
    else { /* ... */ }    
}
```

Comment: Any ways to use `myenum` as `myclass` template parameter when `myenum` is declared inside of `myclass`?

Comment: @user3600124: yes, you can use `template<auto value>`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - But you need a valid specialization of `myclass` to refer to the enumeration.

Comment: With `template <auto value>` I get `error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'`

Comment: Then your compiler doesn't support (or isn't configured to use) C++17. Either move the enum outside the class so you can refer to it, or accept a non-type parameter of the enum's underlying primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a way to keep the template feature only on the specific function and not the whole class.
The price to pay to go from "run-time" class instance to "compile-time" function call is this `mycall()` function that contains this `switch case` statements.

```
#include <iostream>
enum myenum { first, second };
template <myenum E> void myfunc();
template <> void myfunc <first>(){
    std::cout << "First" << "\n";
}
template <> void myfunc <second>(){
    std::cout << "Second" << "\n";
}
class myclass {
private:
    myenum e;
public:
    myclass(myenum e): e(e){};
    void mycall() const{
        switch(e){
            case first:
                myfunc<first>();
                return;
            case second:
                myfunc<second>();
                return;
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    myenum e = first;
    myclass instance(e);
    instance.mycall();
}
```